# xp_regread in Linux Container

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker

I'm running the following query in a Linux based SQL Server container:

```
EXEC master..xp_regread

     @rootkey = N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',

     @key = N'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\',

     @value_name = N'ProductName',

     @value = @Prodname OUTPUT
```

First question would be why does this even work, being a linux based container... and then for some reason if I check the values of the Prodname variable it's set to "Windows 8 Enterprise". Is it defaulted or something for compatibility reasons?

Comment: See https://techcrunch.com/2017/07/17/how-microsoft-brought-sql-server-to-linux/

Comment: Thank you for the link @Charlieface . So if I understood correctly it'd be the "SQL SO" layer that's returning the incorrect OS version as a result of the query i specified in my question?

Comment: I don't think it's *incorrect*, it's just not telling you what you think it is. It's telling you that the subsystem presents features of Windows 8 Enterprise. It probably doesn't support Windows 10 specific features for example. In other words: it's not what it *is*, it's how it *behaves*.

Comment: It is also undocumented - which means you shouldn't be using it in the first place. Perhaps you can use sys.dm_os_windows_info?